# Cocoa control for setting shorcuts

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, macos, keyboard-shortcuts

I want to build a preferences window for my Cocoa application.  Is there a tutorial or example of how a control that sets shortcuts works?

Comment: You do realize that setting keyboard shortcuts is a systemwide feature available in System Preferences, right?

Comment: I prsume/hope that it's for functionality like setting a system-wide hotkey like Adium does.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check out [Shortcut Recorder](http://wafflesoftware.net/shortcut/).